# Jumping to top of page when using jQuery hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to hide/show some divs depending on what button is clicked. Every time I click a different button to show a certain div, it jumps to the top of the page. I'm also using Ruby on Rails if that is relevant. I've tried using return false as well, but that isn't working either. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new-event-button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#edit-events').hide();
        $('#delete-events').hide();
        $('#new-event').slideDown();
    });
    $('#edit-events-button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#new-event').hide();
        $('#delete-events').hide();
        $('#edit-events').slideDown();
    });
    $('#delete-events-button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#new-event').hide();
        $('#edit-events').hide();
        $('#delete-events').slideDown();
    }); 
});
```

View Code:

```
<button id="new-event-button">New Event</button>
<button id="edit-events-button">Edit Events</button>
<button id="delete-events-button">Delete Events</button>

<div id="events-forms">
    <div id="new-event">
        <%= render :partial => "new_event", :locals => { :event => Event.new(:timeline_id=>@timeline.id) } %>
    </div>

    <div id="edit-events">
        <%= render :partial => "edit_events", :locals => { :events => current_user.events } %>  
    </div>

    <div id="delete-events">
        <%= render :partial => "delete_events", :locals => { :events => current_user.events } %>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which web browser are you using?

Comment: The slideDown() jquery animation scrolls you to the top of the div for the animation.  Everything in your code is perfect

Comment: I'm using Firefox. I've just checked in Chrome and it jumps to the top of the page too. Is it possible to specify which div to scroll to for the animation so that it doesn't scroll to the top of the page?

Comment: do those render as anchor tags with `href="#"` by any chance?

Comment: No they don't - they just render a form or a table. I think retanik has got the solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if the div#events-forms you are filling has no height when you click the buttons, it's height will become 0 and then expand again to fit it's content. Thats what triggering the browser to jump back up, because there is no more content to display.

-If possible you can give the containing div#event-forms a fixed size, so only the content is changing and not the height of the element.

```
#events-forms{
border: 1px solid black;
height:400px;
```

-Otherwise you could maybe look into changing the height of the containing div first (with javascript/jquery) to fit the data you want to paste into it.

if you use the following css snippet you can see the div growing and expanding, this might make it easier to understand why you are being set to the top of the page.

```
#events-forms{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I think that's what is going wrong, I looked with the border and you are right, there is a point where the div has no content, and therefore no height. I've fixed it for the time being by writing javascript to scroll down to the bottom when you click the button, will change this to something to change the height of the div. And it works fine now. Thanks for your help!